# Rich Text field not displaying properly in visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, richtext

I have a rich text area field in my Campaign object populated by my Marketing Users.
Once active, Campaigns are displayed in a visualforce page in a Partner portal to a different set of Users.
When I display the rich text field, I am using the below code:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!selectedCampaign.richField__c}" escape="false"/>
```

Even then, the display is not rendering correctly, like

1. "Italics" are not displayed
2. Ordered Lists are showing as unordered
3. For bold, I have to substitute "b" with "strong"

Can anyone help me with this please, thanks.

Comment: did you ever resolve this?